# Send argument values to new terminal

Tags: bash, macos, osascript

I want to open new terminal and pass some values on OSX. I tried this code:

```
open_new_terminals_automatically()
{
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd $1; $2"'
}

# call the function and pass arguments
open_new_terminals_automatically "/root/var/fome_path" "some_commnds -argument"
```

This is very simple example to explain what I want to do.
How I can implement it to run as bash script on OS X.

Comment: To do that, I usually create an here-doc bash file with all the commands needed and then I execute a new terminal only executing that here-doc created which contains all the commands you need

Comment: Can you some me please example using my script?

Comment: By the way is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

What you have almost works, except you need double quotes instead of single quotes for the variable expansion to work properly.

Just create a script `run.sh` with contents

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $1; $2\""
```

Then you can call it with `sh run.sh "/root/var/fome_path" "some_commnds -argument"`.

If you want this all done in one script, then just do

```
open_new_terminals_automatically()
{
    osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $1; $2\""
}

# call the function and pass arguments
open_new_terminals_automatically "/root/var/fome_path" "some_commnds -argument"
```